# Is there a workaround for the error-insight bug in the IDE?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

[image]

XE2 will mark an error in the editor, usually about missing member functions (as shown in the picture). However it wil compile OK and the code will run just fine.
If you ask for a list using <kbd>CTRL + SPACE</kbd> it will give the correct list.

**Is there a workaround/solution for the above bug in the Delphi XE2 IDE?**
In such a way that I don't get incorrect markings for errors in the editor?

Note that this question: [Delphi XE2 background IDE compiler unable to find source path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632506/delphi-xe2-background-ide-compiler-unable-to-find-source-path) signifies why the error is there, but does not list a solution.

Comment: I gave up on Error Insight since it's first incarnation. 10 delphi releases later and it still doesn't work ...

Comment: Alt+T, O, C, C, C, C, Alt+E, Enter

Comment: Did you try using the declared capitalization?

Comment: I'll try that.., no that does not help, I'll have to turn it off. Putting the full path in does not help either, `System does not contain a member TObject`. Fixing the library paths as per this suggestion does not help either: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18103517/650492

Comment: Turn if off, then write your own Error Insight parser and IDE plugin. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Solution, thats works for me in Delphi 2007, XE2 and 10.2.x Tokyo:

1. Compile/Build your project
2. Close your project (Files -> Close all)
3. Reopen your project

The wrong error marks should have gone away now, at least for a while... :-/